# Is there a temperature sensing utility for linux that will read a ryzen 1700 cpu?

Tags: cpu, temperature, amd-processor

Is there a temperature sensing utility for linux that will read a ryzen 1700 cpu? I have been looking for such a utility and cannot find one.
Psensor and xsensor does not work, nor does lm-sensor.
The bios of the motherboard (GA-AB350M-Gaming 3) reads temps ok, but that is only when I am in the bios and not the running the os.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: We only support official versions of Ubuntu.  Besides that: Datasheet for Family 17h CPUs is not published by AMD so the maintainers of those sensor programs can not fix this until this is release.

Comment: More discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/68lyug/ryzen_issues_on_linux/

Comment: The it87.ko driver is too old and does not support newer chipsets https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1740736

Answer (score 8):

The kernel module that worked for me is `it87`
https://github.com/groeck/it87

I have an ASUS Crosshair Hero VI.
https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?92313-linux-lm_sensors-it87-driver

I am using ArchLinux with the 4.11 kernel. To get it working I ran

```
sudo modprobe it87 force_id=0x8622
sudo sensors-detect
```

You may need to use a different `force_id` value. The recommended list from the repo is 0x8622, 0x8628, 0x8728, and 0x8732.

To get the module loaded at boot time I had to create the following files as root.

```
# /etc/modules-load.d/it87.conf
# Load it87 for Ryzen motherboard and CPU sensors
it87

# /etc/modprobe.d/it87.conf
options it87 force_id=0x8622
```

Answer (score 6):

I have an exact Ryzen 1700 and did the below instruction found on forums to see the temperature sensors.

I have an `Ubuntu 17.04` with `kernel 4.11.3` and an `Asus X370 PRO` mobo. and this does not work for me but you can try these commands and leave a reply in the comments.

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors git
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
git clone https://github.com/groeck/nct6775
cd nct6775/
make
sudo cp /proc/kallsyms /boot/System.map-`uname -r`;
sudo make install
sudo modprobe nct6775
sudo sensors-detect
watch -n1 sensors
```

alternatively you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors git
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
git clone git://github.com/groeck/it87.git
cd it87
make
sudo cp /proc/kallsyms /boot/System.map-`uname -r`;
sudo make install
sudo modprobe it87
sudo sensors-detect
watch -n1 sensors
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have a Ryzen 1700 and ASRock AB350M mobo.  Using kernel 4.9.  I believe the nct6775 module from Git only provides the motherboard's temperature reading of the CPU, not the internal temperature of the CPU: https://pastebin.com/JRV2xBrc  I believe this is what CPUTIN is.  For me at least, getting the it87 module working is probably essential.  More discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/68lyug/ryzen_issues_on_linux/

Comment: In my case, the chip is probably a Nuvoton, not ITE.  Appropriate module: https://github.com/groeck/nct6775

Nuvoton discussion: https://github.com/groeck/nct6775/issues/49

Comment: I have a 1600X and an MSI B350 GAMING PRO CARBON, works for me! Debian with Kernel 4.11